# application/vnd.google-apps.documen Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-docs-api

I am using java for file uploading, I want to upload the file as "Google Docs" from docx, When i set MIME type as "application/vnd.google-apps.document", but it throws error

{
"code" : 400,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"location" : "media.mimeType",
"locationType" : "other",
"message" : "Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content.",
"reason" : "invalidContentType"
} ],
"message" : "Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content."
}

Here is my code

Drive service = getDriveService();
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
fileMetadata.setName("sample");

```
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\sample.docx");


    String type ="application/vnd.google-apps.document";


    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata,new FileContent(type,filePath))
            .setFields("id")
            .execute();
    System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Please help solve this issue for file uploading as Google Docs

Answer (score 0):

String type1 ="application/vnd.google-apps.document";

com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata.setMimeType(type1),new FileContent(type1,filePath))
.setFields("id")
.execute();